# I have implemented IOS Slide Menu Navigation View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, navigation-drawer

I have implemented iOS slide menu navigation controller in my app and its working fine earlier. But somehow now its left menu view controllers is coming black screen. Please suggest if someone faced this issue. Below code I have mentioned in Appdelegate.m didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                         bundle: nil];
self.navigationController = (UINavigationController*)[mainStoryboard
 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"navBar"];

self.landingScreen = (SlideNavigationController*)[mainStoryboard
                                                  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"FirstViewController"];

self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


LeftMenuViewController *leftMenu = (LeftMenuViewController*)[mainStoryboard
                                                             instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"LeftMenuViewController"];
self.landingScreen = [SlideNavigationController sharedInstance];
self.landingScreen.leftMenu = leftMenu;
// Creating a custom bar button for right menu

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:SlideNavigationControllerDidClose object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    NSString *menu = note.userInfo[@"menu"];
    NSLog(@"Closed %@", menu);
}];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:SlideNavigationControllerDidOpen object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    NSString *menu = note.userInfo[@"menu"];
    NSLog(@"Opened %@", menu);
}];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:SlideNavigationControllerDidReveal object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    NSString *menu = note.userInfo[@"menu"];
    NSLog(@"Revealed %@", menu);
}];
```

[image]

Comment: did u have give identifier to storyboard id?

Comment: make sure your self.navigationController is not nil.

Comment: Yes I have mentioned it. This is working fine earlier than yesterday evening. I have yesterday just replaced the NSLog with //**NSLog and build sent to the client and its show like the images. Today I have again interchange the //**NSLog with NSLog. But its still show the above.

Comment: no. I have mentioned it like     self.navigationController = (UINavigationController*)[mainStoryboard
     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"navBar"]; and this navigation controller is connected with view controller

Comment: When I mentioned the wrong identifier to storyboard for left menu view controller. Its show error at the time of compilation after giving correct identifier its build successful like above image.

Comment: NSLog printed is SlideNavigationController has not been initialized. Either place one in your storyboard or initialize one in code

Answer (score 0):

Earlier one mistake by replacing the NSLog with //**NSLog is the issue which is replaced the NSlog in the SlideNavigationController.m

//Earlier
    if (singletonInstance)
        //**NSLog(@"Singleton instance already exists. You can only instantiate one instance of SlideNavigationController. This could cause major issues");

//After removing this //** from the NSLOG now its working fine
    if (singletonInstance)
         NSLog(@"Singleton instance already exists. You can only instantiate one instance of SlideNavigationController. This could cause major issues");

Thanks to Bond and Keyur to giving their feedbacks.